# How much memory used in Erlang VM?

Tags: erlang

i want to konw this data struct will use how much memory in Erlang VM?

```
[{"3GPP-UTRAN-FDD", [{"utran-cell-id-3gpp","CID1000"}, "1996-12-19t16%3a39%3a57-08%3a00", "1996-12-19t15%3a39%3a27%2e20-08%3a00"]}]
```

In my application, every process will store this data in self's loop data, and the numbert of this proces will be 120000.

The result which i test:

don't store this data, the memory will be:

```
memory[kB]:  proc 1922806, atom    2138, bin   24890, code   72757, ets  459321
```

store this data, the momory will be:

```
memory[kB]:  proc 1684032, atom    2138, bin   24102, code   72757, ets  459080
```

So the big difference is the memoery used by `proc`: `(1922806 - 1684032) / 1024 = 233M.`

After research, i find an insterting thing:

```
L = [{"3GPP-UTRAN-FDD", [{"utran-cell-id-3gpp","CID1000"}, "1996-12-19t16%3a39%3a57-08%3a00", "1996-12-19t15%3a39%3a27%2e20-08%3a00"]}].
B = list_to_binary(io_lib:format("~p", L)).   
erts_debug:size(B). % The output is 6
```

The memory just use 6 words after using binary? How to explain this?

Comment: When I do it this way in the shell, I get respectively 288 and 284 for flat_size and size??? so I havn't any clue.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, forgot to convert to binary, then I get the same result: 6, bot no clue either :o)

Comment: @Pascal From this link:http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html, the memory size for binary is `3..6 + data (can be shared)`.

Comment: there is something wrong when we measure the size like this, see my answer (cannot fit in a comment)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two useful functions for measuring the size of an Erlang term: `erts_debug:size/1` and `erts_debug:flat_size/1`. Both of these functions return the size of the term in words.

`erts_debug:flat_size/1` gives you the total size of a message without term-sharing optimization. This is guaranteed to be the size of the term if it is copied to a new heap, as with message passing and ets tables.

`erts_debug:size/1` gives you the size of the term as it is in the current process' heap, allowing for memory usage optimization by sharing repeated terms.

Here is a demonstration of the differences:

```
1> MyTerm = {atom, <<"binary">>, 1}.
{atom,<<"binary">>,1}
2> MyList = [ MyTerm || _ <- lists:seq(1, 100) ].
[{atom,<<"binary">>,1}|...]
3> erts_debug:size(MyList).
210
4> erts_debug:flat_size(MyList).
1200
```

As you can see, there is a significant difference in the sizes due to term sharing.

As for your specific term, I used the Erlang shell (R16B03) and measured the term with `flat_size`. According to this, the memory usage of your term is: 226 words (1808B, 1.77KB).

This is a lot of memory to use for what appears to be a simple term, but that is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thansk for you quick answer. Now, we find that the momory for this data is too big, so how can i decrease the memory usage? For example, how to refactor the struct for this data?

Comment: interresting. @BlackMamba if the size is too big for your usage, think about replacing all the internal lists by binaries (it can make sense depending on the operation you have to perform on these strings) then the size change from 226 (R17.1) to 39

Comment: @Pascal How to replace all theh internal lists to binary? use list_to_binary?

Comment: yes, this will convert each string to binary. I have tried this keeping the original structure, I guess it may be important for further work: `[{S1,[{S2,S3},S4,S5]}] = T.` then `B1 = list_to_binary(S1).`... and finally evaluate `erts_debug:flat_size([{B1,[{B2,B3},B4,B5]}])`. For your particular application, I can't say when and where it is appropriate to build the new term.

Comment: @Pascal I have updated my question, when i change to binary, the memory changes from 226 to 6 words.

Comment: What your are looking for is changing strings `"..."` (which are implemented as lists in Erlang, to binaries `<<"...">>`. So you would create your binary-using-data like this ```LB = [{<<"3GPP-UTRAN-FDD">>, [{<<"utran-cell-id-3gpp">>,<<"CID1000">>}, <<"1996-12-19t16%3a39%3a57-08%3a00">>, <<"1996-12-19t15%3a39%3a27%2e20-08%3a00">>]}].```.  You still will be able to pattern-match on them, and their size is smaller (44 in total).

Comment: Regarding your question about 6-words. If binary is big enough it could be shared between processes, which have both it's benefits and disadvantages. If you are looking for real optimization for your domain, you should try to understand what are you doing. I would reccoment watching those https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbzH0L_0pxI https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuCYL0X-8f4  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuPaX11vZyI (first is "light", rest are presented by guy who is writing this part of VM).It should give you more perspective on what you can do.

Answer (score 3):

the size of the whole binary is 135 bytes when you do it `list_to_binary(io_lib:format("~p", L)).`, if you are on a 64 bit system it represents 4.375 words so 6 words should be the correct size, but you have lost the direct access to the internal structure.

Strange but can be understood:

```
19> erts_debug:flat_size(list_to_binary([random:uniform(26) + $a - 1 || _ <- lists:seq(1,1000)])).                                                                                  
6                                                                                                                                                                                   
20> erts_debug:flat_size(list_to_binary([random:uniform(26) + $a - 1 || _ <- lists:seq(1,10000)])).                                                                                 
6                                                                                                                                                                                   
21> size(list_to_binary([random:uniform(26) + $a - 1 || _ <- lists:seq(1,10000)])).                                                                                                 
10000                                                                                                                                                                               
22> (list_to_binary([random:uniform(26) + $a - 1 || _ <- lists:seq(1,10000)])).                                                                                                     
<<"myeyrltgyfnytajecrgtonkdcxlnaoqcsswdnepnmdxfrwnnlbzdaxknqarfyiwewlugrtgjgklblpdkvgpecglxmfrertdfanzukfolpphqvkkwrpmb"...>>                                                       
23> erts_debug:display({list_to_binary([random:uniform(26) + $a - 1 || _ <- lists:seq(1,10000)])}).
{<<10000 bytes>>}
"{<<10000 bytes>>}\n"
24>
```

This means that the erts_debug:flat_size return the size of the variable (which is roughly a type information, a pointer to the data and its size), but not the size of the binary data itself. The binary data is stored elsewhere and can be shared by different variables.

Comment: you are right. But how can i understand this `Binary`: `3..6 + data (can be shared) ` in this link:http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html

Comment: I edited the answer to give my understanding of these numbers.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but i onlu accept one answer,